# Can we make our own web server to host a websites and respond to HTTP requests?

Tags: iis, webserver

A web server responds to an HTTP request and sends the client a set of HTML, CSS, and JS files.

After we build a website or a web application, we usually have to host it on a well-known web server like IIS or Apache to make it accessible all around the world (on the internet).

Can't we just make our own web server so that it can responds to all incoming HTTP requests that the client sends to our computer without having to use IIS?

Comment: IIS required. Some random tips [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/asp-net-hosting-options-cs). (Old but may have some useful bits.) Maybe ask on https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: You can feel free to develop your own HTTP server, but keep in mind to make a really secure implementation takes years of experience and resources. That's why most people go and choose vendor products, or major open source ones.

Answer (score 0):

As wazz and Lex says, you could build your own server to listen the special port and handle the request based on your requirement, but it contains performance and security issue.

If you still want to build it by yourself. I suggest you could refer to some existing server like [KestrelHttpServer](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer).